# issues with the javascript addlistener submit functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code where i am blocking the code to stop its processing if the error happens

```
var objEditForm = document.getElementById("EditForm");    
objEditForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
                        
                        var error = 0;
                        $("##cell,##fax").on("invalid", function() {
                            let error = 1;
                            if($(this).val() == '') {
                                $(this).focus();
                            }
                        });
```

at the bottom i have this

```
if(error == 1) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
```

and defined the `var error = 0;` at the top, it just goes inside that jquery code and does nothing, it alerts me 0 and then submits the form.

any idea what i am doing wrong here

Comment: `$("##cell,##fax")` throws an error because that’s not a valid selector.

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry i was wrong .. thats write you did mistake in write selector in jquery

if "cell,fax" is elements id then its used wrongly in  jquery..

```
it should be like "#cell"  "#fax"..
```

it would be nice if you use jquery its pretty easy.apply even on your submit button i assum your button id is submit ok.

```
             $("#submit").click(function(e)){
             e.preventDefault();
                    var error = 0;
                    $("#cell,#fax").on("invalid", function() {
                        let error = 1;
                        if($(this).val() == '') {
                            $(this).focus();
                        }

                    });
```

but i am still not getting your cell and fax doing

Comment: Please [edit] your previous post. Don’t add another answer.

Comment: its a typo mistake, i have only one # instead of two, but how can i keep my current function and add validation to it so it can work properly